# How to get the product count from the url's for the manufacture

Tags: magento

I have the following Url’s  "wool-thread.php?manufacturer=153"

I want to get the product count from the url

ie. Products count for the category having the manufacture attribute "153"

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter product collection by the manufacturer attribute. Here is working code.

```
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

    $products->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer');
    $products->addFieldToFilter(array(
        array('attribute'=>'manufacturer', 'eq'=> $option_id,          
    )));
   $products->joinField(
      'stock_status',
      'cataloginventory/stock_status',
      'stock_status',
      'product_id=entity_id', array(
        'stock_status' => Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Status::STATUS_IN_STOCK,
        'website_id' => Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId(),
      )
    );
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

    $pro_count =  $products->count();
```

Where Option id is the manufacturer id. In your example it is 153.
It will return filtered collection of enabled product, visible products, and in stock products. After that count the products.

Comment: Thanx,
I think the above code  will show only the manufacturer list of products based on option_id (example it is 153),
but i want to show the products in category having that manufacturer products
like example if i am in some category and i want to get the count of  manufacturer of that category, then how can i get that?
wool-thread.php?manufacturer=153
i want  the manufacturer of wool category

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like :

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('manufacturer');
$collection->addCategoryFilter(Mage::registry('current_category'));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer',array('eq'=>'153')); 
echo $collection->count();
```

or

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(Mage::registry('current_category'))
   ->getProductCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
   ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', array('eq' => 153));
```

then

```
$usedAttributeValues = array_unique($products->getColumnValues($attributeCode));
$attributeModel = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeCode);

$usedAttributeValues = $attributeModel->getSource()->getOptionText(
    implode(',', $usedAttributeValues)
);
```

See https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/4039/9489 for the use of getSize or count on collection.

Comment: Thanx,
I think the above code  will show only the manufacturer list of products based on option_id (example it is 153),
but i want to show the products in category having that manufacturer products
like example if i am in some category and i want to get the count of  manufacturer of that category, then how can i get that?
wool-thread.php?manufacturer=153
i want  the manufacturer of wool category

Comment: You never spoke about the count of manufacturers before :) I edited the answer according to your comment.

Comment: then you can select my answer for the people that come after and as a "reward"